# Better way to Add fields up and display total

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have a an xpage(see below), that shows several rows with number fields and 3 columns (Regular, Overtime, Total).

I have this code on each field under regular and overtime (onBlur):

```
var reg1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("#{id:reg1}").value) || 0;
var over1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("#{id:over1}").value) || 0;
var total1 = reg1 + over1;

document.getElementById("#{id:total1}").value = total1;

document.getElementById("#{id:total1}").disabled = true
```

Eventually, I'll have more rows that I need to add. What would be the best way to add them all so I can show a total for regular column and a total for overtime column?

Any comments on my code above is also appreciated.

See all xpage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="TestHrs"></xp:dominoDocument>

</xp:this.data>


<xp:table style="width:383.0px">
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>Regular</xp:td>
        <xp:td>Overtime</xp:td>
        <xp:td>Total</xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xe:djNumberTextBox id="reg1"
                value="#{document1.rgHr1}">


                <xe:this.onBlur><![CDATA[var reg1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("#{id:reg1}").value) || 0;
var over1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("#{id:over1}").value) || 0;
var total1 = reg1 + over1;

document.getElementById("#{id:total1}").value = total1;

document.getElementById("#{id:total1}").disabled = true]]></xe:this.onBlur>
            </xe:djNumberTextBox>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xe:djNumberTextBox id="over1"
                value="#{document1.ovHr1}">





                <xe:this.onBlur><![CDATA[var reg1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("#{id:reg1}").value) || 0;
var over1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("#{id:over1}").value) || 0;
var total1 = reg1 + over1;

document.getElementById("#{id:total1}").value = total1;

document.getElementById("#{id:total1}").disabled = true]]></xe:this.onBlur>
            </xe:djNumberTextBox>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xe:djNumberTextBox id="total1"
                value="#{document1.toHr1}">
            </xe:djNumberTextBox>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xe:djNumberTextBox id="reg2"
                value="#{sessionScope.reg2}">
                <xe:this.onBlur><![CDATA[var reg2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("#{id:reg2}").value) || 0;
var over2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("#{id:over2}").value) || 0;
var total2 = reg2 + over2;

document.getElementById("#{id:total2}").value = total2;

document.getElementById("#{id:total2}").disabled = true]]></xe:this.onBlur>
            </xe:djNumberTextBox>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xe:djNumberTextBox id="over2"
                value="#{sessionScope.over2}">


                <xe:this.onBlur><![CDATA[var reg2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("#{id:reg2}").value) || 0;
var over2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("#{id:over2}").value) || 0;
var total2 = reg2 + over2;

document.getElementById("#{id:total2}").value = total2;

document.getElementById("#{id:total2}").disabled = true]]></xe:this.onBlur>
            </xe:djNumberTextBox>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xe:djNumberTextBox id="total2"
                value="#{sessionScope.tot2}">

            </xe:djNumberTextBox>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>&#160;&#160;Total Regular&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Total Overtime<xp:br></xp:br>
<xe:djNumberTextBox id="totalRegular"></xe:djNumberTextBox>
&#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160;

<xe:djNumberTextBox id="totalOver"></xe:djNumberTextBox></xp:view>
```

Comment: You might just want to call one function in your onBlur event that recalculates the whole table. You are not talking about thousands of values, so the time will be negligible. I also would not save the result in a (disabled) field, but render it into a cell in the row,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to sum several inputs, maybe you could set the same css Class for them, and then use a css selector to get all of them and do the maths:

```
<xe:djNumberTextBox styleClass="reg"></xe:djNumberTextBox>
```

then you can use a csjs function like this:

```
// i.e. pass to the function '.reg'
function getSumByClass(strClassName) {
    var sum = 0;
    var allInputs = dojo.query(strClassName);
    for (var i = 0, l = allInputs.length; i < l; i++) {
        sum += parseFloat(allInputs[i].value);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Also looking at your code, for a better layout I would use css padding / margin properties instead of several spaceblank HTML chars.

Comment: Thanks! What event would I put this function on so it updates the total field after each number is entered?

Comment: You can use onblur for instance

Comment: I just tried it and I get a NaN. the variable allInputs[1] returns this: [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: check that the styles class are only set to the inputs!